# how to compare 2 times in 24 hour format to check if 1 time is before another time

Tags: javascript, time

I have time strings in 24 hour format like 20:50 and 23:00

now i want to make a method in javascript to determine if 1 time is earlier then the othertime. i have done this in php like so:

```
function isLater($time1, $time2) {
$time1 = new DateTime($time1);
$time2 = new DateTime($time2);

if ($time1 > $time2) {
return true;
}
return false;
}

function isEarlier($time1, $time2) {
    $time1 = new DateTime($time1);
    $time2 = new DateTime($time2);

    if ($time1 < $time2) {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

my question is, what is the best approach to do this in javascript?

Comment: This is pretty ambiguous and broad. It's hard to say what you are using it for,  so a best "best" approach is kind of arbitrary without knowing more.

Comment: we deliver for stores. but we have opening and closing times. so if we open around 12:00 and the store is open from 10:00 i want to check if the open time from the store is before our time. if so.. then we show closed

Comment: You can literally use the exact same logic in your JS. Just changing the language a bit.

Comment: I'm guessing that saying 'the best way' is another way to phrase 'just give me the code'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same structure as you have done in PHP, you could do like this:

```
function isLater(time1, time2) {
  if (time1 > time2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isEarlier(time1, time2) {
  if (time1 < time2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Because JavaScript will consider "a" to be less than "b" and "2" to be less than "3", there is no need to convert to a datetime.

If you want to make the code even shorter, your could make the function like this:

```
function isLater(time1, time2) {
  return time1 > time2;
}

function isEarlier(time1, time2) {
  return time1 < time2;
}
```

This shorter version would even work in PHP (assuming you add the $ signs for the variables).

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a common value and compare. Converting to Date object is effectively converting to a time value in milliseconds, but in this case it's simpler to convert to say minutes since you don't have the date part. This assumes that both dates are on the same day of course:

```
function toMinutes(time) {
  var b = time.split(':');
  return b[0]*60 + +b[1];
}
```

Now compare the two values converted to minutes:

```
if (toMinutes(timeA) < toMinutes(timeB)) {
  // timeA is before timeB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot parse arbitrary hour formats to Dates like you are providing.  If you know that the 24 hour formats are always in the form `XX:XX` you can simply compare the strings:

`'20:50' > '23:00' === false`